Why did my edge disappear here?
The edge seems to disappear with the bottom edge when it is rotated to a specific angle. Is there a way to solve this? I think it's the lighting problem and I wishes to render this with Eevee but I'm not familiar with the light and transparency setting with eevee yet.



It looks like these are the faces generated by the Solidify modifier, so either disable the Show Backface of the material (under Material > Settings) or disable your modifier?

No, like I am using the solid modifier to create a thick edge so I can't disable that modifier I tried to disable the show blackface too but that gives me the same result as disabling the solidify modifier. What I am saying is I wish to get the same effect of being able to see the inside of the model(the visible edges) but with the correct perspective. In my case, the bottom edge seems to be overlapping instead. It's not a great explanation but I hope you understand what I am trying to say.

I donn't know if you can fix it, Eevee is not accurate regarding glass, if you're using Cycles as render engine it should work fine though

I see, thanks for your information!
